# I can´t import repositories (Azure Devops) from manifest.xml file

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, migration, devops, manifest

I’m in the research phase to migrate all our Azure Devops repositories to GitLab, there are hundreds of repositories… According to the GitLab documentation, I can use the option of a manifest.xml file, the example structure is very basic, I tried, but I always get an error, with no details.

Where can I get or some one have one example a complete example of the mass import of repositories, making use of the manifest file? Repositories aren´t public, so, we will need authentication, how can i do this?

This is the structure of the manifest.xml file i tried.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <manifest><remote  name="myorganization"  fetch=".."            review="https://myorganization.visualstudio.com/"/><default revision="main"            remote="myorganization" sync-j="4"/><project path="AF.Deletion" name="myproject/_git/AF.Deletion" groups="testsroix" /></manifest>`

GitLab correctly takes the url of the repository.
For example: https://myorganization.visualstudio.com/myproject/_git/AF.Deletion

I have also tried to add authentication credentials to Azure Devops, with access token, git credentials, username and password.

[Error listing the repositories in the manifest file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqiiG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I could reproduce the issue. This is because the import process failed in authentication to read from an Azure DevOps private repo and we should authenticate against [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#create-a-pat) of our Azure DevOps accounts.

Here is the correct manifest.xml which worked for me during the test.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote name="AzureDevOps" fetch=".." review="https://AlvinZhao:<xxPxxAxxTxx>@<YourAzureDevOpsOrgName>.visualstudio.com" />
  <default revision="main" remote="AzureDevOps" sync-j="4"/>
  <project path="GitLabProject1" name="TheProjectName/_git/ADORepo1" groups="Group-TestMigrationManifest"/>
</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Alvin, finally work for me.